# Open Riser Stairs / Removing carpeting and converting to hardwood

Tags: stairs, carpet, hardwood-refinishing

We have a staircase from the first floor to the second floor.  The stairs are open riser, with the treads *wrapped* in carpet.  The reach a landing and then transition to closed risers.

[image: View of open riser stairs]

Some treads are a bit loose.  So, we're already working to remove and repair a single tread.

[image: Replacing the tread after the screw heads sheared off]

[image: Image of stair tread with worn carpet]

I noticed the treads appear to be solid wood.  **Is this an opportunity to replace the treads with solid hardwood or use plywood with a hardwood veneer + bullnose around the existing treads?**

Is the process for refurbishing open stairs similar to closed risers:

1. Remove carpet
2. Cover treads with thin hardwood or plywood with hardwood veneer
3. Add bullnose to the front of the tread

A few basic questions:

- Is this a conventional project?  I don't see many examples on the web.  This suggest that it is not common.  Why?  Are there important reasons not to replace the carpet on open riser stairs with wood?
- What is the conventional method of covering the underside of the tread (see image below)?  The portion of the tread that faces away from those that are traveling up/down the stairs (e.g. the underside of the tread)?
- Is adding 1/2 inch to the top of the tread going to make the first step noticeably *rise too high*?  Will it make the last step before the landing *rise too little*?

[image: Image from underneath the stairs, looking up]

Comment: The rise will only be affected at the 1st step from the main floor, where it will be higher, and at the last step before the landing where the rise will be shorter. 1/2" isn't really what I'd consider "thin" plywood, I'd go for something more like 1/8" or 1/4" plywood, which you can get with a nice, hardwood surface. You can then put that on the bottom of the steps, and cover both front & back with a bullnose to hide the edges.

Comment: Nice.  Fair enough.  Wasn't sure if 1/8" was so thin that the plywood would "dent" quickly with use.

Comment: A 100lb lady in stilettos with a 1/4" heel is exerting 400psi with her weight on 1 heel. That will likely dent the surface layer of 3/4" the same as it would 1/8" plywood. Under normal circumstances, once the plywood is over a solid substrate (like your stair tread) the 1/8" plywood should be just as strong as 3/4". AFAIK, the surface layer on both is the same thickness, the difference is how many layers are between the surfaces.

Comment: Your questions are quite broad and imply that there's some sort of convention for what you're doing, which may not be the case. That's not ideal here. Instead, provide details about _your_ project and ask _specific_ questions about your challenges. Don't expect us to write a style guide for general consumption.

Comment: The question title asks about hardwood but the body of the question talks about Plywood?

Comment: @alaska man there are hardwood plywood veneers and yes the outer skin is denser than Douglas fur.   I have seen all hardwood plywood but that was many years back and it came from the east coast I just remember it was hard on saw blades.

Comment: I hope the images describe the situation more clearly.  @isherwood, I am not trying to execute a general project; I am trying to do something very specific.  The lack of examples on the web suggest that it is unusual and I don't understand why.  If it is unusual, does that mean I should exercise caution - it's not advised or easy?  Or is it just that it is uncommon b/c my house was built in 1963?

Comment: @AlaskaMan - I suggest plywood b/c it is much cheaper than hardwood.  A plywood with a hardwood veneer is much less expensive than solid hardwood where I live.  I could do it all with 1/4 in thick solid hardwood or a Douglas fir plywood with a hardwood veneer.  Is the veneer too thin to use on stair treads?  Will it just bend / dent because the Douglas fir plywood is soft?

Comment: You're probably not finding many example online because there aren't many examples of open stairs like these left. Most have been converted to traditional style, closed riser _ages_ ago because this went out of style around the time your house was built. Focus on the _how do I do my stairs_ for this question and don't worry about what anyone else has done.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to address your questions, though they're still a bit nebulous.

**Is this an opportunity to replace the treads with solid hardwood?**
Sure. Why not? As far as I'm concerned, *a weekend* presents such an opportunity.

**Is this a conventional project?**
No. Why does that matter?

The reason may be that there aren't many open-riser stairs to begin with, and it's not often that stair treads get replaced in general. That doesn't mean *you* can't or shouldn't.

**What is the conventional method of covering the underside of the tread?**
I'm not quite sure what this means. If you're installing wood treads they'll be wood on the bottom, too. If you're wondering about the steel brackets, I'd paint them or have them powder-coated, maybe. Stainless might be another option if you want high-class. You'd have to have a machine shop cut sections from angle stock and drill for bolts. I might invert them for an exposed style and so you can fit the treads well to the stringer/skirt. Speaking of, obviously you'll need to strip and refinish that.

**Is adding 1/2 inch to the top of the tread going to make the first step noticeably rise too high?**
Well, it would, but you're reworking your mounts anyway, so you can set them to the proper height.

**A few other thoughts...**

Tread options that come to mind:

- Solid oak (not really *that* expensive if you buy them from a big box store)
- Bullnosed construction-grade pine/fir lumber (2x10 or 12)--I've built such a set in my own home and it was beautiful

Some general notes:

- Wooden treads can be slippery; consider placing silica grit in the upper varnish or wrapping them with a thin runner
- Open-riser stairs are actually illegal in many cases nowdays for safety reasons--more than a few broken legs have resulted from slips through the void
- Recognize that you have fewer stringers than modern stairs; be aware of how much strength and stiffness you'll need in a tread for safety and a quality feel

Comment: Somebody posted that open-riser stair modifications would trigger a permit and cost more than it is worth.  The reality is that the carpet needs to be replaced and/or the treads need to be refinished.  I wasn't sure how to verify the claim that open-riser stairs may not be legal.  Now that you've raised it as well, seems like I should investigate.

Comment: Or play the dumb/grandfather card. Your call. I wouldn't think of this as a permit situation.

Comment: Code in my area is "a 4 inch sphere must not be able to pass between the stairs".  The carpeted treads comply right now.  Adding a little wood to thicken up the treads and adding a thick bullnose with a slight over hang should easily allow them to comply.

Comment: Both of those ideas present aesthetic weirdness. You'll have to decide whether strictly meeting modern code (which may not apply to your project) is important enough to put in that extra effort and deviate from a clean design.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you are looking to do but I helped my neighbor cover the steps in his split entry home. He bought the stair treads from Home Depot or Lowes. We cut the treads to size, glued and nailed as necessary and added riser boards to match. When done the stairs looked great and he was satisfied. He did not notice a big problem with the top and bottom step being too high or too low to cause a trip hazard.

Hope this helps with your project.

Comment: Sounds like you replaced the entire tread; you did not try to "cover it" with plywood and bullnose.  Is this correct?

Comment: The finished wood treads he bought were glued directly to the existing treads. The existing treads were not removed, just covered. Go to Home Depot or Lowes and check out the wood coverings.

Comment: @d. george that makes sense.  Since this is an open stair, seems like I need (x4) pieces of wood to completely enclose the existing tread... otherwise it will look a little odd from underneath.